# Error installing packages on the user account with curl and git

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, curl, git

I just installed Arch, and and a few Arcolinux spices here and there and configuring my fresh install I have noticed that when i use curl as a regular user in gives me an error like:

```
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
Cloning Oh My Zsh...
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/usr/share/oh-my-zsh': Permission denied
Error: git clone of oh-my-zsh repo failed
```

And on top of that, when i use sudo, it downloads and installs the pkg on the root account.(in the root directory):

```
$ sudo sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
Cloning Oh My Zsh...
Cloning into '/root/.oh-my-zsh'...
```

Also when I use git clone as a regular user, it cloned the packages in the / partition, next to to the **/root /home /bin /sbin /etc** directories. I know that is not normal. What can I do to fix this issue and have the packages installed as normal?

Comment: A non-root user can't write to /. Something is not right, either your system or your description. By the way, `git clone` should write to the current directory.

Comment: If I were you, I'd read the install script. It starts with about 20 lines of instructions. *Cloning into '/root/.oh-my-zsh'* is explained by `default: $HOME/.oh-my-zsh`.